# logstash graphite output use variable metric name

Tags: variables, filter, logstash, metrics, graphite

I am using logstash (1.4.2 on centos) with metrics filter and graphite output to graph access log HTTP response codes.

The basic configuration works. Here is my working config file.

```
input {
  file {
     path => "/var/log/nginx/access.log"
  }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
  metrics {
    meter => [ "http.%{response}" ]
    add_tag => "metrics" 
  }
}
output {
  if "metrics" in [tags] {
    graphite {
      host => "localhost"
      port => "2003"
      metrics => [ "mymetric.http.200", "%{http.200.rate_1m}"]
    }
  }
}
```

And the output is shown correctly e.g.

```
mymetric.http.200 0.8430647815095349 1413557739
```

However I want to install the **same** config file on multiple servers (hosts) and include the host name in the metric name.

I tried to use the %{host} variable in the metrics definition e.g.

```
metrics => [ "mymetric.%{host}.http.200", "%{http.200.rate_1m}" ]
```

But this does not send anything to graphite and I get

```
 "Message is empty..."
```

in the logstash debug output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently having a similar problem. As a work around I added the pattern I wanted to the meter definition.

```
meter => [ "mymetric.%{host}.http.%{response}" ]
```

To test what's going out to graphite you can use an output with the graphite codec.

```
stdout {
    codec => graphite {
        fields_are_metrics => true
    } 
}
```